# $\begin{align} p_{n+1} &= p_n\ \,+\,\ c\\ p_{n+2} &= p_{n+1}+d\end{align}\ \Rightarrow\ p_n p_{n+1} \equiv c(c+d)\ \pmod{\!p_{n+2}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was observing the modulo answers to the following expression.
Let $p_{n+2}$, $p_{n+1}$ and $p_{n}$ be three consecutive primes;
$$
p_{n} p_{n+1} \mod{p_{n+2}}
$$

If, we consider a small subset of primes having the following property.
$$
p_{n+2} - p_{n+1}=6
$$
$$
p_{n+1} - p_{n}=6
$$

Then, for all primes greater than $59$ satisfying above property, I’ve observed the below to always hold good.

$$
p_{n} p_{n+1} \equiv 72 \mod{p_{n+2}}
$$

Although, the number of examples I’ve checked are a few (all primes less than 1600 having this property); I will be thankful to the stack community, if someone could help me with proving or disproving the same.

Comment: In general, if we have positive integers $x,y,z$ with $y=x+u , z=y+v$ , we have $$xy=(z-v-u)(z-v)\equiv v(u+v)\mod z$$

Comment: Why adjective "sexy" ? Is it standard or have you invented it ?

Comment: @Aziz, I think you can use other words replacing 'sexy' if it is not mentioned in other sources ?

Comment: @JeanMarie It is a common terminology for consecutive primes with difference $6$ , for $2$ we have "twin-primes" , for $4$ we have "cousin-primes".

Comment: $\bmod p_{n+2}\!:\,\ \begin{align}\color{#c00}{p_{n+1}}&\color{#c00}{\,\equiv -6}\\ p_n&\equiv -12\end{align}\!\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{p_{n+1}}p_n \equiv (\color{#c00}{-6})(-12)\equiv 72\,$ by [Congruence product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Comment: $\!\bmod p_{n+2}\!:\ \color{#c00}{p_{n+1}} = p_{n+2}-d\equiv \color{#c00}{-d},\,$ so $\,p_n = \color{#c00}{p_{n+1}}-c \equiv \color{#c00}{-d}-c\,$ so $\,p_{n+1}p_n \equiv -d(-d-c)$ by the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), slightly more generally. OP is case $c = 6 = d\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$p_np_{n+1}=(p_{n+2}-12)(p_{n+2}-6)=p_{n+2}^2-18p_{n+2}+72\equiv 72\mod p_{n+2}$$

Comment: Thank you sir. Got the answer sir.

Comment: Looking at your answer, a small doubt sir. What is special about 47,53,59 primes for which this doesn’t hold?

Comment: We have $13\equiv 72\mod 59$ , $72$ is here just not the smallest positive representant.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

If $p_n=2k+1$ then $p_{n+1}=2k+7$ and $p_{n+2}=2k+13$.

Then $p_np_{n+1}=4k^2+16k+7=(2k+13)(2k-5)+72=p_{n+2}(2k-5)+72$.

So, $p_np_{n+1}\equiv72 \pmod {p_{n+2}}$.

I am thinking about $59$. Cities. I think Aziz is from 57.

Comment: For, 47,53,59; 2491 mod 59=13 mod 59

Comment: Also sir, by looking at your answer; now I would like to clarify that this property is not special for primes. It will hold good for all the odd numbers having this property.

Comment: @Aziz In fact, it holds for every arithmetic progression $(x,y,z)$ with difference $6$ , also for even ones.

Comment: $p_{n+2}(2k-5)$?

Comment: Primes are odd after $2$...

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).